# Using a separate submit button on a "Change Password" Web UI Control?

Tags: asp.net

**Intro:**

I should start by saying I am not an ASPX developer. I mainly do PHP and C# on the windows side. I know enough to get me by.

We have a developer currently working on a web system for a client. A part of the system is where users go to change their profile details. (Name, telephone number etc)..

**What we currently have:**

He had put the "Change Password" on a separate page that is linked from the profile page. This is using the ChangePassword control. I have moved this onto the same page as the other fields, but only works with the included submit button with the control.

**What we would like to do:**

We would prefer that we could use the "Save" button at the bottom of the page that saves all the settings, rather than have a separate "Change Password" button.

I have looked online for a solution but seems that no one has done this with the control before. I can't find any documentation on how to do this. Is it possible?

Comment: I should say that our developer said this is impossible to do. I don't trust him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place textboxes for `Current Password` and `New Password` in your page rather than using change password web control and then call the built-in asp.net membership method to [change password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.changepassword(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.ChangePassword(txtCurrentPwd.Text, txtNewPwd.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems pretty simple. I really think our developer is screwing us over by saying this is impossible to do. He recently also said that we shouldn't be using HTML5 or CSS. and instead should have used HTML tables for the layout... Also that he should be the one to do this and charge £100 an hour to do. If only my boss would listen!